# Merge Ruby Arrays into Multidimensional Array

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to merge the following two arrays into a multidimensional array?

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = ['D', 'E', 'F']
```

Desired result:

```
z = [['A', 'D'], ['A', 'E'], ['A', 'F'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E'], ['C', 'F']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = ['D', 'E', 'F']

result = x.product(y)

puts result.inspect
```

Comment: I was waiting for somebody to come along and blow my answer out of the water. A begrudging +1. :)

Comment: Wow. That's exactly what I was looking for. I was looking through the Ruby Core API and somehow missed this one.

Comment: @JasonSwett I definitely learned from your solution. A +1 to you as well. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, although not necessarily the simplest possible way:

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = ['D', 'E', 'F']

result = []

x.each do |x|
  y.each do |y|
    result << [x, y]
  end
end

puts result.inspect
```

**Update**: here's a more concise way:

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = ['D', 'E', 'F']

puts x.map { |x|
  y.map { |y| [x, y] }
}.inspect
```

Comment: This might be the best way. I could replace your `y.each` with `result << y.map{|item| [item, x] }` I believe.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. I'll accept your answer when it lets me. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: No problem. Another thought, and maybe you already know about this, but I might personally use `collect`, an alias for `map`, instead of `map` here. Even though the two functions do the same exact thing, I find the `collect` name to be more intent-revealing in these kinds of cases.

Comment: Okay, I was going to accept this, but the other answer does exactly what I wanted in the most concise way possible. Using `#product` seems to be the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: Or, even better, use the other guy's better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is like this:

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = ['D', 'E', 'F']

print x.concat(y).each_slice(2).to_a    # => [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], ["E", "F"]]
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `x.zip(y)`?